# Add two number in a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my index.html

```html
<html>
<body>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://togetherjs.com/togetherjs.js"></script>
  <form id="form_table">
  <table class="table table-hover small-text" id="tb">
  <thead>
      <tr class="tr-header">
     
     <th>Invoice Number</th>
     <th>Date</th>
     <th>Net</th>
     <th>Vat(%)</th>
     <th>Gross</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
     
     <tbody id="row_div">
     <tr>
   <td>
    <input type="text" id="invoice_no" class="form-control" name="invoice_no"  />
   </td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" id="date" class="form-control date_Picker" name="date1" />
   </td>              

            <td>
    <input type="text" id="net" name="Net1" onchange='gross_amount()' class="form-control" >
   </td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" id="vat" name="Vat1" onchange='gross_amount()' class="form-control">
   </td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" id="gross" name="Gross1" class="form-control" readonly />
   </td>
             
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" >Submit</button>
<button  type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="addMore" onclick="add_tr()" >Add</button>
<button  type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="remove" name="delete" onclick="remove_tr()" >Delete</button>

</form>

<script>

$(function () {

    $(document).on("click", ".date_Picker", function () {

        $(this).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        }).datepicker("show");
    });
});

var intTextBox = 1;
//FUNCTION TO ADD ROW
function add_tr() {
    if (intTextBox > 0) {

        intTextBox = intTextBox + 1;
        var contentID = document.getElementById('row_div');
        var newtr = document.createElement('tr');
        newtr.setAttribute('id', 'floorstrText' + intTextBox);
        newtr.innerHTML = "<td><input type='text' name='invoice_no" + intTextBox + "' id='invoice_no" +intTextBox+ "' class='form-control'/></td>"
            + "<td><input type='text' name='date" + intTextBox + "'id='date" + intTextBox + "' class='form-control date_Picker' ></td>"
            +"<td><input  name='Net" + intTextBox + "' type='text' class='form-control'  id='net" +intTextBox+ "' onchange='gross_amount()' class='form-control'/></td>"
            +"<td><input  name='Vat" + intTextBox + "' type='text' class='form-control'  id='vat" +intTextBox+ "' onchange='gross_amount()'  /></td>"
            +"<td><input  name='Gross" + intTextBox + "' type='text' class='form-control'  id='gross" +intTextBox+ "' readonly/></td>";
        contentID.appendChild(newtr);
        gross_amount();
    }

}
function remove_tr() {
    if (intTextBox != 0) {
        var contentID = document.getElementById('row_div');
        contentID.removeChild(document.getElementById('floorstrText' + intTextBox));
        intTextBox = intTextBox - 1;
    }
}

function gross_amount() {
  var Net = document.getElementById('net').value;
  var Vat = document.getElementById('vat').value;
  var Gross = parseInt(Net) +(parseInt(Vat)*parseInt(Net)/100); 
  if (!isNaN(Gross)) {
   document.getElementById('gross').value = Gross;
   
  }
  if(intTextBox > 0)
  {
   var Net = document.getElementById('net'+intTextBox).value;
      var Vat = document.getElementById('vat'+intTextBox).value;
      var Gross = parseInt(Net) +(parseInt(Vat)*parseInt(Net)/100); 
   if (!isNaN(Gross)) {
    document.getElementById('gross'+intTextBox).value = Gross;  
      }
  } 
 }

$(document).ready(function () {
    gross_amount();
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that after adding multiple rows the javascript function gross_amount() is working only on first & last row, on other rows its not working. Datepicker has no problem.

Comment: __Identifers in HTML must be unique__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made changes to the code as well as html

What you are doing is using variable 'intTextBox' as all point of reference which won't work i have passed parameter to gross_amount() function so that it will work properly

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://togetherjs.com/togetherjs.js"></script>
<form id="form_table">
    <table class="table table-hover small-text" id="tb">
        <thead>
        <tr class="tr-header">

            <th>Invoice Number</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Net</th>
            <th>Vat(%)</th>
            <th>Gross</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="row_div">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="invoice_no" class="form-control" name="invoice_no"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="date" class="form-control date_Picker" name="date1"/>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="text" id="net1" name="net1" onchange='gross_amount(1)' class="form-control">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="vat1" name="vat1" onchange='gross_amount(1)' class="form-control">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="gross1" name="gross1" class="form-control" readonly/>
            </td>

        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="addMore" onclick="add_tr()">Add</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="remove" name="delete" onclick="remove_tr()">Delete</button>

</form>

<script>

    $(function()
    {

        $(document).on("click", ".date_Picker", function()
        {

            $(this).datepicker({
                changeMonth : true,
                changeYear : true,
                dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy'
            }).datepicker("show");
        });
    });

    var intTextBox = 1;
    //FUNCTION TO ADD ROW
    function add_tr()
    {
        if(intTextBox > 0)
        {

            intTextBox = intTextBox + 1;
            var contentID = document.getElementById('row_div');
            var newtr = document.createElement('tr');
            newtr.setAttribute('id', 'floorstrText' + intTextBox);
            newtr.innerHTML = "<td><input type='text' name='invoice_no" + intTextBox + "' id='invoice_no" + intTextBox + "' class='form-control'/></td>"
                + "<td><input type='text' name='date" + intTextBox + "'id='date" + intTextBox + "' class='form-control date_Picker' ></td>"
                + "<td><input  name='Net" + intTextBox + "' type='text' class='form-control'  id='net" + intTextBox + "' onchange='gross_amount(" + intTextBox + ")' class='form-control'/></td>"
                + "<td><input  name='Vat" + intTextBox + "' type='text' class='form-control'  id='vat" + intTextBox + "' onchange='gross_amount(" + intTextBox + ")'  /></td>"
                + "<td><input  name='Gross" + intTextBox + "' type='text' class='form-control'  id='gross" + intTextBox + "' readonly/></td>";
            contentID.appendChild(newtr);
        }

    }
    function remove_tr()
    {
        if(intTextBox != 0)
        {
            var contentID = document.getElementById('row_div');
            contentID.removeChild(document.getElementById('floorstrText' + intTextBox));
            intTextBox = intTextBox - 1;
        }
    }

    function gross_amount(id)
    {
        console.log(id);
        var Net = document.getElementById('net' + id).value;
        var Vat = document.getElementById('vat' + id).value;
        var Gross = parseInt(Net) + (parseInt(Vat) * parseInt(Net) / 100);
        if(!isNaN(Gross))
        {
            document.getElementById('gross' + id).value = Gross;
        }

    }

    //    $(document).ready(function () {
    //        gross_amount();
    //    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, as you are adding rows dynamically so each row must have unique ID. When you add new TR then 2 new TD also gets added with ID 'net' & 'vat'. So, on same page you will be having multiple TD with same ID and javascript engine will not be able to identify where to apply the effect. So, we can do like this :

```
<input type="text" id="net" name="Net1" onchange='gross_amount(this)' class="form-control" >
<input type="text" id="vat" name="Vat1" onchange='gross_amount(this)' class="form-control">
```

In Javascript do like this

```
function gross_amount() {
    var Net = $(this).val() 
    ............
 }
```

Other way is instead of ID use class of the input tags